# Do not redirect if some RewriteCond is matched

Tags: apache

I have written some rules in httpd.conf file. It works fine. I want to write a RewriteCond such that it should match 1st and 2nd parameter and should not redirect if its matched.

If URL is mobile/login or mobile/admin redirect should not happen, how do i do this.

-- Updates --

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!(android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile|Nokia*| Opera*)" [NC]
 RewriteCond $1 !web
 RewriteCond $2 !login
 RewriteCond $2 !admin
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/index.php [R,L]
```

Here the $2 part does not work for me.

Comment: It may be helpful if you included the relevant section of your `httpd.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `!` character at the start of the pattern in your RewriteRule.

See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for more information.

**Update**

$2 does not work for you because your RewriteRule pattern has only one set of capturing parentheses.  This is probably what you're looking for:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!(android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile|Nokia*| Opera*)" [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !(web|mobile/login|mobile/admin)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/index.php [R,L]
```